# How do I save data to my express server with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-resource

So I been working on this for a few hours and I am suck. So at first I had a cors issue, and solved it. Then I tried several things. What I want to do is to have `$resource` without making a custom post method. My api is set up using restful standards. `POST /artist` accepts json with two properties. name and password.

So I tried a few things, as I been on stackoverflow looking at solutions. Here is what I've tried and they all end up posting no data to my server. The data is being set by ng-model and I can see the data with $scope.artist.

attempt 1

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log('artist:', $scope.artist);
    ArtistSignup.save($scope.artist).$promise
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log('res:', res);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error:', error.data.message);
        });
    };
```

attempt 2

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log('artist:', $scope.artist);
    $scope.newArtist = new ArtistSignup();
    $scope.newArtist.data = $scope.artist;
    $scope.newArtist.$save($scope.artist)
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log('res:', res);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error:', error.data.message);
        });
    };
```

attempt 3

```
$scope.artist = new ArtistSignup();
$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log('artist:', $scope.artist);
    $scope.artist.$save()
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log('res:', res);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error:', error.data.message);
        });
    };
```

my factory, i've tried with and without `{name: '@name')`

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('artistSignup')
        .factory('ArtistSignup', function (backendUrl, $resource) {
            return $resource(backendUrl + '/artist/:name', {name: '@name'});
    });
}());
```

Comment: **backendUrl** are you passing this? also update the post with your errors in each attempts.

Comment: backendUrl is just `http://localhost:1337`

Comment: where is it in the code. update the errors to the post

Comment: `app.module(....., [...]).value('backendUrl', 'http://localhost:1337')`

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured it out... It was the express sanitizer I was using. It was creating an undefined req.body :( Rip...